# Electron App not Working After Packaging - Electron Forge

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-forge

So I am trying to Package my application using Electron-forge.

Tested it Locally using "electron-forge start" and it's running fine.

Also, while packaging for Linux platform [ running npm run forgeL64] the operation was successful.
[image]

"forgeL64": "npm run forge -- --platform=linux --arch=x64",
"forge": "npm run build && cross-env DEBUG='electron-forge:*' electron-forge make",

But while running the application after packaging it's not even opening the Electron Shell.

I tried all the Solutions which I can like electron-log (for which I am not seeing any Logs in the specified location of Linux Dir). Also, tried using electron-unhandled which is also not showing me any kind of error while I am executing the app.